# Is this 'interfering' an adjective or a verb?

Tags: vocabulary

> A lamp flickered on. It was Hermione Granger, wearing a pink bathrobe
>   and a frown. 
>       "You!" said Ron furiously. "Go back to bed!" 
>       "I almost told your brother," Hermione snapped, "Percy -- he's a prefect, he'd put a stop to this." 
>       Harry couldn't believe anyone could be so **interfering**.
>
> –– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

It’s easy for me to read ‘interfering’ as a predicative complement, but its adjective meaning is found only in front of noun phrases. Is it a predicative or a continuous aspect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "interfering" is acting as the predicate of the clause "anyone [Hermione] could be so interfering", and it's being used in the sense of "being a busybody".

In this passage, Hermione is threatening to tell Ron's older brother what Harry and Ron are up to, and Harry is complaining about Hermione's willingness to interfere in their (Ron and Harry's) business.

Answer (score 3):

Pretend you don't know what the last word of the sentence is for a moment:

> Harry **couldn't believe** that anyone could be **so** *<adjective>*.

Harry is (inwardly) expressing exasperation that someone possesses a certain negative trait (expressed by a following adjective phrase) to such a large extent.

In other words, it's clear that *so* (meaning "to such a large extent") is modifying a following adjective phrase.  Even if you don't know what the next word is, you can be pretty sure it'll be an adjective!  Take a look at some other ways you could fill in the blank:

> Harry **couldn't believe** that anyone could be **so *stupid***.
>   Harry **couldn't believe** that anyone could be **so *callous***.
>   Harry **couldn't believe** that anyone could be **so *self-centered***.

Parsing it as a verb form would be infelicitous (and only marginally grammatical at best).  This would require *so* to mean "in that manner" instead, which clashes with the overall tone and meaning of the sentence.  So the alternative is very unlikely.

Our only choice is to read *interfering* as an **adjective** meaning ["meddlesome"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interfering).  This is true even if *interfering* isn't commonly used as a predicate adjective.